# Как преобразавать обьект класса в list?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, list

Мне нужно автоматически фиксировать появление обьектов класса

```
class InstaPost:

        def __init__(self, who, image, who_image="gui/oPhone/contacts/default.png", where=None, comments=[], like=False, answer_variants={}):
            
            self.who = who
            self.image = image
            self.who_image = who_image


            self.where = where or ""
            self.comments = comments

            self.my_answer = None
            self.like = like

            self.answer_variants = []

            for answer_variant_name, answer_variant in answer_variants.items():

                answer_variant = answer_variant if isinstance(answer_variant, (list, tuple, set)) else [answer_variant]

                self.answer_variants.append( AnswerOnPost(self, answer_variant_name, *answer_variant) )
```

Я хочу сохранять все атрибуты обьектов во внешний список ввиде вложеного листа.

Но `not_object = list(post)`

Выдает ошибку `TypeError: "InstaPost" object is not iterable`

Были похожие вопросы с решением реализовать методы `__iter__`, `__getitem__` и `keys`

Не совсем понятно как это сделать тут.

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял, какой конкретно результат вы хотите. Атрибуты объекта хранятся в словаре `объект.__dict__`

Comment: Как вы получили post?

Comment: И о каких объектах идёт речь?

Comment: Post это сам объект уже. Нужен список атрибутов этого объекта, по которому можно будет делать иттерацию.

Comment: Можно делать итерацию по `объект.__dict__`